# исключение при проверке версии java

Tags: python

Пытаюсь обработать ситуацию, когда java не установлена:

```
try:
  java_version = subprocess.check_output(['java', '-version'], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  #print(java_version)
except Exception as e:
  java_version = '0'
```

Корректно ли я это делаю?

Comment: у внешнего кода нет явных признаков того, что выдернуть версию не получилось. лучше напрямую возвращать None в случае exit code != 1, да и исключение ловить вряд ли стоит - насколько понимаю, оно будет выброшено только в случае, если все пойдет совсем на юг, и об этом конечный пользователь должен будет как-то узнать (e.g. сейчас у вас может вообще не запуститься процесс, но об этом никто не узнает, все будут считать, что джава не установлена)

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите прочитать вывод команды `java -version`, то код корректный. Насколько в целом такой подход правильный зависит как эта информация позже используется (может вы хотите: `update-alternatives --list java`).

Вариация на тему:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from subprocess import check_output, STDOUT

try:
    java_version = check_output(['java', '-version'], stderr=STDOUT)
except FileNotFoundError:   # java command is not found 
    java_version = None
```

`CalledProcessError` можно не ловить, а позволить по стеку подняться, так как `java -version` не должна ненулевой статус возвращать в обычной ситуации (`java` отсутствует или `java` присутствует и на настоящую `java` команду указывает).

`java_version` либо `None` либо байты здесь.